# Insert missing records in a list with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc

We have a table with periods, and other child tables with these periods and values for combinations of product + location.

Based on selected periods, I would like to add any missing rows in the child tables. I have come up with the following code, which seems to work just fine. But I would like to know if there is a simpler or more efficient way of doing this, since I have to repeat this for a number of tables.

```
public static void SeedActivityData(int startPeriod, double endPeriod, IList<DAL.OMS_StockStatus> stockStatus)
{
    DAL.EFDbContext dbFilter = new DAL.EFDbContext(0, stockStatus.FirstOrDefault().Product, startPeriod, endPeriod);
    var period = dbFilter.Periods.Select(b => b.PeriodID);
    foreach (var item in stockStatus)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> missingFAF = period.Except(dbFilter.OMS_Forecast_Adjustment.Where(a => a.SiteID == item.SiteID).Select(b => b.PeriodID));

        var modelFAF = db.OMS_Forecast_Adjustment;
        foreach (int periodID in missingFAF)
        {
            var modelItem = new OMS_Forecast_Adjustment { PeriodID = periodID, Product = item.Product, SiteID = item.SiteID, Value = 0 };
            modelFAF.Add(modelItem);
        }

        IEnumerable<int> missingRAF = period.Except(dbFilter.OMS_Receipts_Adjustment.Where(a => a.SiteID == item.SiteID).Select(b => b.PeriodID));

        var modelRAF = db.OMS_Receipts_Adjustment;
        foreach (int periodID in missingRAF)
        {
            var modelItem = new OMS_Receipts_Adjustment { PeriodID = periodID, Product = item.Product, SiteID = item.SiteID, Value = 0 };
            modelRAF.Add(modelItem);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some more detailed information? It would be helpful to see some examples of the situations you are trying to address. For instance showing the data/collection before, then after. Thanks! My first thought though is that it looks like you repeat the same iteration and adding twice. You can probably pull that out into a separate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you should create an `Add` method to both the `OMS_Forecast_Adjustment` and `OMS_Receipts_Adjustment` classes.

you are really adding things to the `db` all wrong,  you are creating `new` objects in your code when you don't have to, I think that you really want to add items to a collection variable inside your `db` object.

it should be an `InsertRecord` method

this:

> ```
>     var modelFAF = db.OMS_Forecast_Adjustment;
>     foreach (int periodID in missingFAF)
>     {
>         var modelItem = new OMS_Forecast_Adjustment { PeriodID = periodID, Product = item.Product, SiteID = item.SiteID, Value = 0 };
>         modelFAF.Add(modelItem);
>     }
> ```

Would turn into this

```
foreach (int periodID in missingFAF)
{
    db.Insert_OMS_Forcase_Adjustment(periodID, item.prodeuct, item.SiteID, 0);
}
```

so you actually do your insertion inside of a method in the class that you already have.

This removes the creation of 2 extraneous local variables and puts responsibility where it belongs inside of a method in the object that needs to perform the action.

This can be done on both Foreach Loops

Comment: Thanks Malachi. But how can I implement the InsertRecord method? Or should I now ask this in StackOverflow forum?

Comment: it's a different structure than what you have here, but it is doing pretty much the same thing.  I don't know how they would react to that question on StackOverflow.  and as far as a StackOverflow forum, I didn't know there was one....